# Python. Как сравнить 2 файла XML с удалением совпадающих узлов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

Как сравнить 2 XML файла с удалением совпадающих элементов ? Этим я хочу найти отличия 1 от 2 и наоборот. Можно использовать только библиотеку ElementTree (xmlDiff не надо).

Для образца, File1.xml

```
<root>
    <tag1 v="group" id="1">
        <param1 v="single">Test1</param1>
    </tag1>
    <tag2 v="group" id="2">
        <param1 v="single">Test2</param1>
    </tag2>

</root>
```

File2.xml

```
<root>
    <tag1 v="group" id="1">
        <param1 v="single">Test1</param1>
    </tag1>
    <tag2 v="global" id="2">
        <param1 v="single">Test3</param1>
    </tag2>
    <newtag v="group" id="20">
        <param1 v="single">Test4</param1>
    </newtag>
</root>
```

В итоге должны получиться 2 XML-структуры с несовпадающими узлами и значениями. У меня XML много сложнее и я запутался даже с перебором узлов, не говоря об их удалении. Подскажите вариант, пож.

Comment: Можно в Notepad++  посмотреть https://ibb.co/3hqqJGF

Comment: в теме указан и язык и библиотека...

Comment: Поправьте, пожалуйста, тэги в образце. А лучше, если можете, скиньте ссылки на исходные файлы.

Comment: Исправил неточность, спасибо.

Comment: В общем случае ваш вопрос решается коммерческой организацией. Если как-то можно упростить задачу, допустим важен только текст в тэгах, то возможны скриптовые решения.

Comment: Реализовал сравнение не на XML. Может кому пригодится. Мне нужно сравнить "важные" узлы и "неважные". Для этого преобразую каждый XML в список (в "важных" узлах углубляюсь до записей, сохраняю все атрибуты, в "неважных" определяю кол-во дочерних записей) и имея 2 списка, прохожу по одному, ищу во втором и в случае соответствия удаляю записи. В конце остаются 2 списка - первый то потеряно во второй XML, а второй список - то что добавлено во второй XML. Пример: "plc[1]inf[1][ind] t=word, v="test", proc_id=1, 
cont[1], doc[2], file[1]"